# Single cell e-ink type components?

Tags: e-ink

I'd like to make my own binary watch, and something pretty small. Using surface mount LEDs would work but they use a lot of energy (~30mA a piece for something I'd consider reasonably bright) so there'd have to be a mechanism to "show the time".

Instead of this I'd like to only update my display once per time unit and leave it in a stable state in between - exactly like an e-ink display, thus massively reducing the power requirement.

I only have 6 binary display parts in my design so I really need individual e-ink cells, but I've no idea if this kind of thing even exists!

Does such a component exist? Is this the 'right' line of thinking? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to contact eInk sales rep, to see if you could source eInk displays s.a. the ones used by Sieko watches. Here's the [data-sheet](http://www.eink.com/sell_sheets/Surf%20Sell%20Sheet.pdf).

Comment: Not sure if "bunary" is a typo, but I think eInk's segmented EPD's like [this one](http://store.nexternal.com/eink/6-x-14-starburst-p20.aspx) (5 for $50) may serve you purpose well, and they seem to be not very expensive. However, given that these are developer-samples, availability in larger numbers may be something to check.

Comment: @icarus74 - That looks interesting enough to be an answer. I'll upvote if you post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, eInk is pretty difficult to make yourself. I know of nobody who has managed to make their own. LCD is also verging on impossible to home brew. Your only options are to look for an existing LCD that you can buy and use, or use LEDs.

You don't need 30mA for an LED. We have surface mount LEDs here that are annoyingly bright, even at 1mA! You could go down to 0.25mA and still have a perfectly visible display. These LEDs are [HSMW-CL25](http://uk.farnell.com/avago-technologies/hsmw-cl25/led-smd-0603-white/dp/1652117?Ntt=1652117) from Avago Technologies.

Comment: This has to be the best bet - the link quotes 5mA (but I'm assuming that's maximum current) but a 0.25mA LED would allow constant use of about 5 days on a 180mAh button battery, so with a micro tilt switch to detect when the watch is in "read" orientation would make this last for ages. Now to sort out the oscillator...

Comment: Yeah, at 5mA those things are painfully bright.

Comment: How many LEDs would you be using @jphastings?

Comment: Six (4 hours, 2 hours, 1 hours, 1/2 hours, 1/4 hours, 1/8 hours - so that "6:30am" would be "HHL HLL", and 15:08 would be "HHH LLH")

Comment: So worst case LED current consumption would be 6x0.25mA = 1.5mA.

Answer (score 4):

You could try eInk's segmented [EPD range called SURF](http://www.eink.com/sell_sheets/Surf%20Sell%20Sheet.pdf). Those are apparently used in Sieko watches, apart from bunch of other devices (such as smart batteries, to show charge levels). Development samples seem to be [available for $50](http://store.nexternal.com/eink/6-x-14-starburst-p20.aspx) (for a pack of 5), with three options 7-segment, 14-segment and a simple progress-bar.

Since these are developer-samples, availability in larger numbers may be something to check with the eInk sales rep. Especially so because some [people have faced difficulties](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13937/what-are-some-dirt-cheap-small-e-ink-displays) working with eInk, but situation might have changed now - YMMV.